# WebApiThrottle not blocking any requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Title says it all really.

I'm using https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle to control the number of requests to my webApi, only its not..

I have screwed down the rate lints to ensure that I'm definitely not just sending my requests too slow.

I have switched the `Repository` for no reason other than, just in case.
I have removed and added `EndpointRules`

Nothing I do seems to have any effect.

The full WebApiConfig file is here:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services - moved to web.config
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // API throttling - https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ThrottlingHandler()
        {
            Policy = new ThrottlePolicy(perSecond: 1, perMinute: 1, perHour: 1) // (perSecond: 1, perMinute: 20, perHour: 200)
            {
                IpThrottling = true,
                ClientThrottling = true,
                EndpointThrottling = true,
                EndpointRules = new Dictionary<string, RateLimits>
                {
                    { "/search/", new RateLimits { PerSecond = 1, PerMinute = 1, PerHour = 1 } }
                }
            },
            Repository = new MemoryCacheRepository() //CacheRepository()
        });  
    }
}
```

Can anyone see anything thats obviously wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to have to guess it was a cache think / developer error.
At some point it just started working and my 1 per second rule basically turned off my API - whoops!